# How to use IPC::Run module in perl script

Tags: oracle, perl, solaris, sqlplus

I have this Perl script which connects to sqlplus database and run the below command.

```
my $SQLPLUS='/opt/oracle/product/11g/db_1/bin/sqlplus -S system/coolman7@vsdb';
`$SQLPLUS \@${basePath}/VoucherQuery1.sql $startdate> ${basePath}/QueryResult1.txt`;
```

Now I am trying to run the second command through IPC::Run. I have tried in many ways without any success. like

```
open (WFH1, ">", "${basePath}/QueryResult4.txt");
run('$SQLPLUS \@${basePath}/VoucherQuery4.sql $startdate', '>', \\WFH1);
close(WH1);
```

but it is not able to connect to sqlplus or write to the output file. I have searched in google and in other forums but haven't got any solution. Please help. :)

Comment: I would recommend using [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle) rather than calling out to an external program to interact with a database.  It is much more efficient, secure and flexible.

Comment: Yes... agree with you and for that I wasted my two precious days in installing DBD::Oracle on my Sun Solsaris OS without any success.. I tried everything and at the end I had to quit.. :(

Comment: Check if there is XE oracle for Solaris, as it comes with it's own perl and DBD::Oracle working out of the box.

Comment: @Ankur DBD::Oracle can be a pain in the everything to install.  Try posting your problems installing it as another question?  It will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lexical filehandles makes life much easier in general.  They aren't global, and they will automatically close when they go out of scope.

```
open (my $wfh1, ">", "${basePath}/QueryResult4.txt");
```

It's possible the whole problem is that `open` failed, you're not checking if it succeeded.  You can do this two ways.  First is to do it by hand...

```
my $query_result_file = "${basePath}/QueryResult4.txt";
open (my $wfh1, ">", $query_result_file)
    or die "Couldn't open $query_result_file for writing: $!";
```

Or you can use [autodie](http://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) to do it for you.

```
use autodie;
open (my $wfh1, ">", "${basePath}/QueryResult4.txt");
```

But you don't need to manually open the file at all, IPC::Run will do that for you if you pass it a filename.

The next problem is what you're passing to `run`.  It's in single quotes, which means none of the variables will be interpolated.  You're literally trying to run `$SQLPLUS @${basePath}/VoucherQuery4.sql $startdate`.  You need double quotes.

But it's better to pass your command and arguments as an array ref, that way IPC::Run will handle the shell quoting for you.

Here's a simple example reading a file using `cat`, adding line numbers, and outputting the result to a file.

```
use IPC::Run qw(run);
run ["cat", "-n"], "<", "/etc/passwd", ">", "test.out";
```

Putting it all together...

```
my $SQLPLUS_EXE = '/opt/oracle/product/11g/db_1/bin/sqlplus';
my $SQLPLUS_DB  = 'system/coolman7@vsdb';
my @SQLPLUS_CMD = ($SQLPLUS_EXE, '-S', $SQLPLUS_DB);

run [@SQLPLUS_CMD, "\@${basePath}/VoucherQuery4.sql", $startdate],
    ">", "${basePath}/QueryResult4.txt";
```

Comment: Hi..thanks a lot for your explanation.. I really appreciate.. I am able to apply ur solution now but I wonder this run command is taking longer time that backticks method.. Currently I am running it on test database which has around 10 rows...but in prod I will run it on millions of rows.. is IPC::Run really a more efficient alternative of backticks??

Comment: @Ankur, if you are after top performance, DBI is pretty much the only answer. If you cannot install it on Solaris, try it out on Linux first - just to validate that it works and works fast

Comment: @Ankur IPC::Run is a *safer* and more featureful alternative to backticks.  For a simple command like you have, just piping the output of a command to a file, it's not necessary.  And since you're not reading the output, you should be using `system`.  DBI will be far more efficient than all of that.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.. I was looking for DBI initially.. but I faced uncountable issue while installing DBD::Oracle in my solaris machine.. So I had to go alternate solution..